# What was the first Federation flagship/starship in service?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, federation

Did the Feds have any classes of or starships in service before the NCC1701 Enterprise? I'm curious as to the history of the space exploration operation and which ships began the first voyages into the final frontier.

Comment: Only the NCC-1701-D and NCC-1701-E were flagships - previous incarnations of the Enterprise were not.

Answer (score 5):

In the excellent [Star Fleet Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Star_Fleet_Technical_Manual), the [Federation Charter](http://www.eagle-ms.be/atfs/datas/dos/ufp_07.txt) states that the 'Star Fleet' will initially consist of *planetary fleets* and that members also agree to fund the design of a fleet specifically for Federation use.

> **Article 43**
>
> *All members of The United Federation, in obligation to the maintenance
>   of interplanetary peace and security, agree to make available to Star
>   Fleet, on call of the Federation Council, armed forces, assistance,
>   and facilities, including rights of passage, necessary for the
>   maintenance of interplanetary peace and security;*
>
> **Article 52.**
>
> 1. *There is established a **Star Fleet** as the armed peace-keeping forces of the United Federation of Planets. It shall initially by
>      comprised of contingents assigned to it by members of the United
>      Federation of Planets under Article 43 until such time as facilities,
>      recruitment, and training obviates the necessity of drawing upon the
>      armament of any member*
>
> **Article 53**
>
> 1. *Initial expenditure is granted under these articles of Federation for the design, procurement, and operation of fourteen (14) heavy
>      cruiser type of starships to provide the nucleus of Star Fleet's
>      peace-keeping armed forces. These cruisers shall be capable of
>      extended duration patrol of intra-galactic range, with weaponry
>      appropriate to such class starships. They shall be provided with
>      fire-power superior to that now employed by any member of the United
>      Federation, and appropriate to the tasks expected of them;*

Therefore the first classes of Starships weren't specific classes but rather fleets provided by members. The very first '*class*' of ship designed *specifically* for Star Fleet was a "[Heavy Cruiser](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Heavy_cruiser) Type of Starship"

Answer (score 4):

Well, Yes. The series *Enterprise* explored the voyages of the NX-01 "Enterprise" which was the first ship of Starfleet, before the creation of the Federation.

Comment: Debatable that it was _the_ "flagship" though

Comment: @HorusKol Though it was the only ship they had, and thus can't really be called a flagship, it certainly served the function of a flagship.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz a flagship is a command ship in charge of a fleet - it's called a 'flag'ship because it carries teh fleet commanders flag - the NX-01 was an independent explorer